# golang XML not unmarshal-ing properly

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, go

The XML format I need to unmarshal is as follows:

```
data := `
<table>
    <name>
        <code>23764</code>
        <name>Smith, Jane</name>
    </name>
    <name>
        <code>11111</code>
        <name>Doe, John</name>
    </name>
</table>
`
```

I have attempted the following structs and code to no avail:

```
type Customers struct {

    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"table"`
    Custs []Customer
}

type Customer struct {

    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"name"`
    Code string `xml:"code"`
    Name string `xml:"name"`
}

...

var custs Customers
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &custs)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}

fmt.Printf("%v", custs)

for _, cust := range custs.Custs {

    fmt.Printf("Cust:\n%v\n", cust)
}
```

The range prints nothing out, and printing `custs` only gives me `{{ table} []}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct structure is the following:

```
type Customer struct {
    Code string `xml:"code"`
    Name string `xml:"name"`
}

type Customers struct {
    Customers []Customer `xml:"name"`
}
```

You can try it [on the playground here](http://play.golang.org/p/D2CCP0dwdo).
The problem is that you don't assign the xml tag for `[]Customer`.

The way you solved this, using `xml.Name` is also correct but more verbose. 
You can review working code [here](http://play.golang.org/p/LJFSctBgSi).
If you need to use the `xml.Name` field for some reason, I would recommend
using a private field so that an exported version of the struct is not cluttered.

Comment: Brilliant - that does work.  For some reason I thought I had to use XMLName to denote the title of the field if it didn't match.

Comment: The purpose for using `xml.Name` is to override the parent tag at runtime as it's value is regarded as well. So you can use the value of the `xml.Name` for the `table` structure and re-use the Customers struct for some similar looking XML structure with a different parent tag name.